# Recursive directory list/analyze function doesn't seem to recurse right

Tags: python, recursion, command-line, filesystems, directory-structure

I wrote what I thought was a straightforward Python script to traverse a given directory and tabulate all the file suffixes it finds. The output looks like this:

```
OTUS-ASIO:face fish$ sufs

>>>         /Users/fish/Dropbox/ost2/face (total 194)
===                    1       1      -
===                  css      16      -----
===                  gif      14      -----
===                 html      12      ----
===                  icc      87      --------------------------
===                  jpg       3      -
===                   js      46      --------------
===                  png       3      -
===                  zip       2      -
```

... which would be great, if those values were correct. They are not. Here's what happens when I run it in a subdirectory of the directory I listed above:

```
OTUS-ASIO:face fish$ cd images/
OTUS-ASIO:images fish$ sufs

>>>         /Users/fish/Dropbox/ost2/face/images (total 1016)
===                  JPG       3      -
===                  gif      17      -
===                  ico       1      -
===                 jpeg       1      -
===                  jpg     901      --------------------------
===                  png      87      ---
```

... It only seems to go one directory level down. Running the script one level up didn't pick up on the 'jpeg' suffix at all, and seemed to miss a good 898 jpg files.

The script in question is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
getfilesuffixes.py

Created by FI$H 2000 on 2010-10-15.
Copyright (c) 2010 OST, LLC. All rights reserved.
"""

import sys, os, getopt

help_message = '''
Prints a list of all the file suffixes found in each DIR, with counts.
Defaults to the current directory wth no args.

$ %s DIR [DIR DIR etc ...]
''' % os.path.basename(__file__)

dirs = dict()
skips = ('DS_Store','hgignore')

class Usage(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

def getmesomesuffixes(rootdir, thisdir=None):
    if not thisdir:
        thisdir = rootdir

    for thing in [os.path.abspath(h) for h in os.listdir(thisdir)]:
        if os.path.isdir(thing):
            getmesomesuffixes(rootdir), thing)
        else:
            if thing.rfind('.') > -1:
                suf = thing.rsplit('.').pop()
                dirs[rootdir][suf] = dirs[rootdir].get(suf, 0) + 1
    return

def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    try:
        try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "h", ["help",])
        except getopt.error, msg:
            raise Usage(msg)
        for option, value in opts:
            if option == "-v":
                verbose = True
            if option in ("-h", "--help"):
                raise Usage(help_message)

        if len(args) == 0:
            args.append(os.getcwd())

        for durr in [os.path.abspath(arg) for arg in args]:
            if os.path.isdir(durr):
                dirs[durr] = dict()

        for k, v in dirs.items():
            getmesomesuffixes(k)

        print ""

        for k, v in dirs.items():
            sufs = v.items()
            sufs.sort()

            maxcount = reduce(lambda fs, ns: fs > ns and fs or ns, map(lambda t: t[1], sufs), 1)
            mincount = reduce(lambda fs, ns: fs < ns and fs or ns, map(lambda t: t[1], sufs), 1)
            total = reduce(lambda fs, ns: fs + ns, map(lambda t: t[1], sufs), 0)
            print ">>>\t\t\t%s (total %s)" % (k, total)

            for suf, sufcount in sufs:
                try:
                    skips.index(suf)
                except ValueError:
                    print "===\t\t\t%12s\t %3s\t  %s" % (suf, sufcount, "-" * (int(float(float(sufcount) / float(maxcount)) * 25) + 1))
            print ""


    except Usage, err:
        print >> sys.stderr, sys.argv[0].split("/")[-1] + ": " + str(err.msg)
        print >> sys.stderr, "\t for help use --help"
        return 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

It seems that `getmesomesuffixes()` is subtly not doing what I want it to. I hate to ask such an annoying question, but if anyone can spot whatever amateur-hour error I am making with a quick once-over, it would save me some serious frustration.

Comment: NB: please excuse the script's employ of getopt boilerplate, global variable use, and myriad other less-than-gorgeous aspects. It's a tool to be banged out and used and not at all a lyrical iambic code-pean from the mouth of a PEP-8 anointed cherubim.

Comment: [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: os.walk 4 life. seems the consensus. thanks

Comment: Btw, your `reduce` calls are strange versions of the functions `min, max, sum`, ie `maxcount = max((1,max(sufs, key=lambda x:x[1])))`

Comment: and the `try: skips.index(suf) except ...` construct means simply `if suf not in skips:`

Comment: THC4k -- good call, I was never into that `try` block.

Comment: every day in every way, I'm getting less and less appallingly ignorant of the builtins and standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, Won't you be better off if you used os.walk

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
    ... do you stuff ..
```

See the example at

- http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

Also look at os.path.splitext(path), a finer way to find the type of your file.

```
>>> os.path.splitext('/d/c/as.jpeg')
('/d/c/as', '.jpeg')
>>>
```

Both of these together should simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import os.path
from collections import defaultdict

def foo(dir='.'):
    d = defaultdict(int)   
    for _, _, files in os.walk(dir):
        for f in files:
            d[os.path.splitext(f)[1]] += 1
    return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = foo()
    for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
        print k, v
```

Comment: thank you sir. -- I am totally on board the os.walk() train. so handy.